# Improving KDB HDB query performance

Tags: kdb

We're currently facing significant delays in query response times from the Historical Database (HDB) component of our tickerplant architecture. Allow me to provide some context to better understand our setup and the challenges we're encountering.

Our architecture revolves around two core tables: the orders table, storing all users' order histories, and the Real-time Database (RDB), which performs an end-of-day write-down to the HDB. As an exchange, We consistently query both the RDB and HDB to retrieve all historical data for a particular user, dating back to their initial joining of the exchange.

The issue lies in the query performance specifically related to accessing data from the HDB. While querying the RDB yields satisfactory response times, querying the HDB is proving to be time-consuming. One of the potential reasons for this could be the current partitioning strategy employed in the HDB.

As it stands, the HDB is partitioned by date, which means that retrieving user order histories requires multiple disk operations to locate the relevant data. Our typical order query resembles SELECT row FROM orders WHERE order_uuid = <order_uuid>. Although the table includes both user UUID (unique identifier of the user) and order UUID (newly created orders will have a new order UUID), partitioning by date necessitates additional disk operations to find the user's complete order history.

One possible solution we're considering is to partition the HDB by user instead of date. This adjustment would streamline the querying process, as the HDB would only need to perform a single disk operation to retrieve a user's entire order history, significantly improving query response times. However, this approach has its drawbacks, particularly for users who trade very frequently. Over time, the table for such users could become excessively large, potentially leading to performance degradation and storage issues.

Given this context, we're seeking insights and alternative approaches to optimize query performance from the HDB while balancing considerations such as query efficiency and storage management. Any suggestions or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: In the date-partitioned table, what column (if any) do you have a p# attribute on? If you don't have a p# on any column then that's one part of the problem. If you do have a p# perhaps you have it on the wrong column for your optimal usage pattern. Also, I presume your query isn't actually `select from orders where order_uuid=` ... are you not supplying a date range `select from orders where date within(x;y), order_uuid=` ? You could change your partitioning to be by user and yes the tables could be big but again the correct use of p# can help. Note that your EOD write will become slower

Comment: unfortunately we don't know when the user traded, so we don't give the date while querying, so has to go thru all the history to find it. Are you saying that with parted attribute large table wont matter ? I still think this will get so large for a user that trade very frequently and it get so big unable to load from disk to memory ?

Comment: Isn't a users first trade date fixed? You could store that per user in a tiny table and use that for date-range lookup. To answer your question - yes, if you know the date range and you have p# attribute on the right column, and you filter on that column first (after date) then you can still retrieve large amounts of data from disk efficiently, especially with parallel worker threads configured.  Of course it still depends on the size of the data.

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally you are not able to cut your search space down given this setup.

I'd consider a two-stage query. First, store a start/end date per order id, potentially in a splayed table. Given a user field and GUID, and applying `p# on user to quickly narrow down the range, this should easily scale to a few hundred million orders or better.

Then this tells you the exact date range you need for the query to get at the order details. Again if you have `p# on sym or user it would help.

Comment: I am confused now, But if you maintain additional splayed table just to store date of the orders creation, you still have to maintain that in memory or on disk right ?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to append to this table at end-of-day, and depending on attribute setup re-sort. You may want to simplify queries for T0 by always sending them to RDB regardless (as mentioned the performance there is ok).

Comment: One other thing I didn't mention - because I've never had reason to try it - is whether applying `u# on disk for GUID makes any sense, as it would give you faster lookups for first phase and should mean no re-sort on EOD. But I don't know if it's faster, and depending on how it's implemented it may mean you map all of the GUID column into memory for every query. However, this is going to be a highly queried column and might find it's way into memory regardless, so that may not be a genuine concern.